# Container not picking up existing Volume or Network when running from docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have created a docker-compose file that will start up Kabana and ElasticSearch containers. I already have created a network and volume for these in my VM. I am using docker compose version 3.4.

Command: `docker volumes ls`

```
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               elasticsearch-data
local               portainer_data
```

Command: `docker volumes ls`

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                 DRIVER              SCOPE
75464cd8c8ab        bridge               bridge              local
587a311f6f4f        host                 host                local
649ac00b7f93        none                 null                local
4b5923b1d144        stars.api.web        bridge              local
```

Command: `docker-compose up -d`

```
ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 33, column 27
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - stars.api.web
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: changeme
      discovery.type: single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.0
    container_name: kibana
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
      - stars.api.web

volumes:
  name: elasticsearch-data:

networks:
  name: stars.api.web:
```

EDIT:
removing the `:` from the name, eg `name: elasticsearch-data` throws the following error:

```
ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', volume 'name' must be a mapping not a string.
```

Comment: Have you tried removing second `:` from `name: elasticsearch-data:`? You should also declared the volume as [external](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external) `external: true` as you have already created it.

Comment: Same for `name: stars.api.web:`.

Comment: @leopal when I add the `external: true` I get `volume 'external' must be a mapping not a boolean.`

Comment: What about just declaring the top-level entry? `volumes:
  my-data-volume-name:`   and services > `db:
    image: db
    volumes:
      - my-data-volume-name:/var/lib/db`

Answer (score 1):

Your yaml is invalid according to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).

Please use the following compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - stars.api.web
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: changeme
      discovery.type: single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.0
    container_name: kibana
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
      - stars.api.web

volumes:
  elasticsearch-data:
    external: true

networks:
  stars.api.web:
```

I assume that you have already created defined volume and network. Note that `external: true` is required when the volume has been created outside of docker-compose context.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, a nice trick to check if you Compose file is valid:

```
docker-compose -f file config
```

If the alternate file is omitted will take `docker-compose.yml` as default.

from the help page:

> config: Validate and view the Compose file

After applying the suggested edits by @leopal,
If you want a "quite" output,

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml config -q 

$ docker-compose -f your.yaml config


networks:
  stars.api.web: {}
services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: changeme
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xmx256m -Xms256m
      discovery.type: single-node
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.0
    networks:
      stars.api.web: null
    ports:
    - published: 9200
      target: 9200
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        hard: -1
        soft: -1
    volumes:
    - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:rw
  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    depends_on:
    - elasticsearch
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.0
    networks:
      stars.api.web: null
    ports:
    - published: 5601
      target: 5601
version: '3.4'
volumes:
  elasticsearch-data: {}
```